# Plot multidimensional data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have records of members in a club and their interests, as in the following:

```
Member A: Football, Swimming
Member B: Swimming, Jooga, Jogging
Member C: Cycling, Football
Member D: Football, Tennis, Cycling
```

Is it possible to plot these in Python so that one can see the different interests members share? Thanks in advance, Adia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple table seems to make more sense than a Venn diagram:

```
import scipy, pylab
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David']
interests = [['Football', 'Swimming'], ['Swimming', 'Jooga', 'Jogging'], 
             ['Cycling', 'Football'], ['Football', 'Tennis', 'Cycling']]
allinterests = list(set(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, interests)))
X = scipy.zeros((len(interests), len(allinterests)))
for i, indinterests in enumerate(interests):
    for x in indinterests:
        X[i, allinterests.index(x)] = 1
pylab.matshow(X, interpolation='nearest', cmap=pylab.cm.gray_r)
pylab.show()
pylab.yticks(range(len(names)), names)
pylab.ylim([len(names)-0.5, -0.5])
pylab.xticks(range(len(allinterests)), allinterests)
pylab.savefig('interests.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying the exact same code you have posted on my machine, but it gives a 'syntax error' message along the colons in the first and second FOR loop. I don't see any wrong syntax here, so what could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry. I left out a parenthesis in the `zeros` line. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html) and see if it offers something suitable for that.

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), another alternative. See also [this example](http://wiki.sagemath.org/interact/misc#AnInteractiveVennDiagram).

Comment: Actually I did before posting my question. I couldn't find something that could fit for mapping the members against their interests. I am sure there is, it's just my limited knowledge about Python.

Comment: Okay. I added another alternative to the answer. I guess something like a Venn diagram might fit your needs.